# Unable to see metrics related to spark for executors

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, jmx, metrics, jmxtrans

After making changes in `metric.properties` and passing relevant arguments in the command line i.e.,

> "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0 org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --conf
>   spark.metrics.conf=./metrics.properties --conf
>   spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0`"

I can only see metrics related to JVM and Kafka (in my case spark in a producer for Kafka) for the executors, when I connect through JConsole. I am unable to see metrics related to spark for the executors. Is there anything that I am missing ?

Note: I can see JVM, Kafka and spark related metrics for the 'driver', when connected through JConsole.

Comment: Is it resolved ?